# SQL - WHERE condition from another table

Tags: sql, join, left-join, amazon-redshift

I have to study how many times a client purchases something on the app for each session. So I have to work with two tables. The first one (called '**sessions**') is structured in this way

*user_id | session_id | start_session_time | end_session_time*

The second one (called '**purchases**') is structured in this way:

*user_id | timestamp | purchase_id*

where user_id, session_id and purchases_id are unique.

My final goal will be to have a table that counts how many times the user purchased in each sessions. The output I would like is:

***user_id |  session_id | start_session_time | end_session_time | nb_purchases***

In my mind it would be a query like:

```
SELECT sessions.user_id, sessions.session_id, sessions.start_time,
       sessions.end_time, count(purchases.purchase_id)
FROM sessions 
LEFT JOIN purchases 
    ON sessions.user_id = purchases.user_id
WHERE purchases.timestamp BETWEEN sessions.start_time AND sessions.end_time
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?

I am using SQL Amazon Redshift.

Thank you in advance,

Andrea

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: You would need to `Group By user_id, session_id` in order to get the correct purchases count per user per session, then query that against the timestamps. Also, seems like a db schema design flaw, since simply adding session_id to the purchases table would give you what you are looking for with a simple query.

Comment: So what's not working for you?  You've defined a story but stated no problem; no error is defined vs what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `left join`, so the condition needs to go in the `on` clause.  Then you also need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT s.user_id, s.session_id, s.start_time, s.end_time, count(p.purchase_id)
FROM sessions s LEFT JOIN
     purchases p
     ON s.user_id = p.user_id AND
        p.timestamp BETWEEN s.start_time AND s.end_time
GROUP BY s.user_id, s.session_id, s.start_time, s.end_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT
    sessions.user_id
   ,sessions.session_id
   ,sessions.start_time
   ,sessions.end_time
   ,COUNT(purchases.purchase_id)
FROM sessions
LEFT JOIN purchases
    ON sessions.user_id = purchases.user_id
WHERE purchases.timestamp BETWEEN sessions.start_time AND sessions.end_time
GROUP BY
    sessions.user_id
   ,sessions.session_id
   ,sessions.start_time
   ,sessions.end_time
```